# I want to import a bulk of data from one excel file to another from row 3 to the last row -1

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code trying to import rows 3 to the last row of the file.

But i get an error on line  `lastrow = SrcWbk.Cells(Rows.Count,"a").End(xlUp).Row`

Once i have this working i want it to import lastrow -1 as the last row of each thing i am importing is a total row.

I am a complete novice and am just trying to play and get a base knowledge.

Thanks for any help it is much appreciated.

```
Sub GetFileCopyData()

   Dim Fname As String

   Dim SrcWbk As Workbook

   Dim DestWbk As Workbook

   Dim lastrow As Long



   Set DestWbk = ThisWorkbook

   Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select a File")

   If Fname = "False" Then Exit Sub

   Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(Fname)

   lastrow = SrcWbk.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

   SrcWbk.Sheets("Processing").Range("A3:lastrow").copy

   DestWbk.Sheets("raw data").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

   SrcWbk.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: I assume the error is _method not supported_ That's because a workbook does not support `Cells`. You have to add the worksheet, possibly  `lastrow = SrcWbk.Sheets("Processing").Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 2):

Not only the line `lastrow = SrcWbk.Cells(Rows.Count,"a").End(xlUp).Row` runs into an error also later on the line `SrcWbk.Sheets("Processing").Range("A3:lastrow").copy`will run into an error because you want to pass the value of lastrow to Range but you just pass the string lastrow to it. It is also not a good idea to declare Fname as a string because you use `Application.GetOpenFilename` which returns a boolean in case Cancel is pressed.
I suggest to fix your code in the following way

```
Sub GetFileCopyData()

Dim Fname As Variant
Dim SrcWbk As Workbook
Dim DestWbk As Workbook
Dim lastrow As Long

    Set DestWbk = ThisWorkbook
    Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select a File")
    If Fname = False Then Exit Sub

    Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(Fname)
    lastrow = SrcWbk.Sheets("Processing").Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    SrcWbk.Sheets("Processing").Range("A3:A" & lastrow).Copy
    DestWbk.Sheets("raw data).Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    SrcWbk.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked like a charm i changed the range to A3:BG & lastrow-1 as it is for multiple columns. Thank you very much for your help